# Start gammu with parameters

Tags: c#, command-line, parameters, gammu

I would like to use `gammu` to send text messages with address and message, but I have a problem with the `gammu` parameters. If I start only the program it runs (`string cmd1 = "c:\\G133\\bin\\gammu.exe ";`). After adding parameters it gives this failure:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified:

Code:

```
string[] sms = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\\temp\\test.txt");

string address = sms[0];
string message = sms[1];

string cmd1 = @"C:\G133\bin\gammu.exe --sendsms TEXT" + " " +  
    "\"" + address + "\" -text " + " " + "\"" + message + "\"";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(cmd1);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

The output looks well:

```
Console.WriteLine(cmd1); - result

C:\G133\bin\gammu.exe --sendsms TEXT +12121234567 -text "Hello"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the overload of `Start` method which takes two parameters:

- First one: the file to run;
- Second one: the parameters

And it will looks like:

```
string app = @"path\to\your\target\app";
string prms = "your parameters";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(app, prms);
```

Comment: the failure is gone thank you but the sms is still not sent. Some command windows comes up and after it closeing so quickly i could not read it :(. Do you have any idea to catch it?

Comment: The executable c# file have to be in gammu config directory .... than it works thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the application and the arguments:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\G133\bin\gammu.exe", "--sendsms TEXT +12121234567 -text \"Hello\"");
```